# Android: How to dynamically change button text based on user input?

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to create a button that changes its text based on user input. So it would say "NAME" and then the user would click it and be able to edit it as if it was a TextView. I have no idea how to place a TextView on top of a button perfectly which is why I am in need of this solution.
This is my button:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/name1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:text="Name"/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you be more specific

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this code:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.name1);
// lets say you have an EditText for your user input
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);

btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        btn.setText(et.getText().toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: You don't need to put a text view on top of a button...the button it self, has one text view inside its view

Comment: Thanks! But how do I place the EditText over the button? That's what my main problem is. Every time I try to do so, it never aligns correctly

Comment: Why you want to do that?

Comment: I just created a new post to extensively explain what it is I am trying to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40205979/how-do-i-align-textview-and-edittext-over-a-button

Comment: Please check it out. Thanks!